# Cannot install SSH Agent Plugin for Jenkins

Tags: java, windows, jenkins, ssh, jenkins-pipeline

I am trying to use the SSH Agent Plugin for Jenkins on a Windows slave:

https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/SSH+Agent+Plugin

The error I am receiving in my job is:

java.lang.RuntimeException: [ssh-agent] Could not find a suitable ssh-agent provider.

The instructions say that the Apache Tomcat Native Libraries need to be installed on the Windows Slave but no instructions on how to install and/or reference them.

Answer (score 1):

Download the native libraries from here:

http://tomcat.apache.org/download-native.cgi

Then extract somewhere on your machine and add to your path environment variable.  Restart Jenkins to be sure it is picked up.

Comment: I assume you talk about adding the apr/bin/x64 dir with the tcnative-1.dll file? I still get the error even though tomcat's startup log even says that it found the native library with ssl support. The path variable in the jenkins job itself also has a path variable that contains the path.

Comment: I wasn't able to get it to work with jenkins.war in a tomcat server, but when running it simply with java -jar jenkins.war the PATH variable is picked up and the ssh agent provider is found.

Comment: Bizarre, perhaps a permissions issue when running as a service vs running as your (presumably) administrator account?

Answer (score 1):

I was able to get ssh-agent to work on Windows by using a version from a pull request that simply uses native shell commands instead of the java implementation in the tomcat native library.

There's only some trivial code change left in the pull request, but it seems to be in limbo until this is fixed. So I had to make the change on the pull request branch, build the plugin locally and then install it via .hpi file directly.

This is the relevant pull request:
https://github.com/jenkinsci/ssh-agent-plugin/pull/2